# unable to resolve module ../Observable from this path

Tags: rxjs, watermelondb

i was doing offline feature in my react native app using typescript and i have used watermellonDB as my local database and i have come across this error how can i solve it?

**`error: Error: Unable to resolve module ../../Observable from C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\projects\work\addo-app\node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\observable\dom\animationFrames.js:

None of these files exist:

- node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\observable(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
- node_modules\rxjs\dist\cjs\internal\observable\index(.native|.android.js|.native.js|.js|.android.jsx|.native.jsx|.jsx|.android.json|.native.json|.json|.android.ts|.native.ts|.ts|.android.tsx|.native.tsx|.tsx)
  2 | Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
  3 | exports.animationFrames = void 0;

> 4 | var Observable_1 = require("../../Observable");
> |                             ^
> 5 | var performanceTimestampProvider_1 = require("../../scheduler/performanceTimestampProvider");
> 6 | var animationFrameProvider_1 = require("../../scheduler/animationFrameProvider");
> 7 | function animationFrames(timestampProvider) {
> at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\projects\work\addo-app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:137:15)
> at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\projects\work\addo-app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:260:43)
> at Object.resolve (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\projects\work\addo-app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:177:21)
> at Graph._resolveDependencies (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\projects\work\addo-app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:432:35)
> at Graph._processModule (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\projects\work\addo-app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:218:38)
> at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
> at async Graph._addDependency (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\projects\work\addo-app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:314:20)
> at async Promise.all (index 3)
> at async Graph._processModule (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\projects\work\addo-app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:263:5)
> at async Graph._addDependency (C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\projects\work\addo-app\node_modules@react-native-community\cli-plugin-metro\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\Graph.js:314:20)`**

after tracking down what is the issue i found out that when i use this line of codes it gives me error

```
const adapter = new SQLiteAdapter({
  schema,
  migrations,
  // jsi: true, /* Platform.OS === 'ios' */
  // (optional, but you should implement this method)
  onSetUpError: error => {
    // Database failed to load -- offer the user to reload the app or log out
  }
})

// Then, make a Watermelon database from it!
export const database = new Database({
  adapter,
  modelClasses: [
    OptionModel,
  ],
})
```

but when I commented them, the error doesn't occur, help please....

i have tried to install Rxjs-compact but nothing worked, i have try to delete the node_modules and reinstall it still not working, i have also clean all caches and rebuilt my project.